# How does ` ... | awk '$1=$1'` remove extra spaces?

Tags: awk

From my understanding, `$1` is the first field. But strangely enough, `awk '$1=$1'` omits extra spaces.

```
$ echo "$string"
foo    foo bar               bar

$ echo "$string" | awk '$1=$1'
foo foo bar bar
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: See also: [How do I trim leading and trailing whitespace from each line of some output?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/102008)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When we assign a value to a field variable ie. value of `$1` is assigned to field `$1`, awk actually rebuilds its `$0` by concatenating them with default field delimiter(or `OFS`) space.

We can get the same case in the following scenarios as well...

```
echo -e "foo foo\tbar\t\tbar" | awk '$1=$1'
foo foo bar bar

echo -e "foo foo\tbar\t\tbar" | awk -v OFS=',' '$1=$1'
foo,foo,bar,bar

echo -e "foo foo\tbar\t\tbar" | awk '$3=1'
foo foo 1 bar
```

For GNU AWK this behavior is documented here:
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Changing-Fields.html

> $1 = $1   # force record to be reconstituted

Comment: Don't rely on `awk '$1=$1'` printing the current record after recompiling it, try `echo -e "0\tbar\t\tbar" | awk '$1=$1'`. Always do `awk '{$1=$1}1'` instead and in general only use an action in a conditional context if you **need** the result of that action to be evaluated as a condition. The only other thing worth mentioning is that assigning to a field will also remove all leading and/or trailing spaces from the record when you use the default FS.

Comment: What does the last `1` signify in `awk '{$1=$1}1'`? @EdMorton

Comment: @annahri it’s a pattern, which always evaluates successfully, and executes the default action (which prints the current record). Adding `1` is a common AWK trick to print the current record, but it does make the program harder to understand for people unfamiliar with the trick in question.

Answer (score 18):

```
echo "$string" | awk '$1=$1'
```

causes AWK to evaluate `$1=$1`, which assigns the field to itself, and has the side-effect of re-evaluating `$0`; then AWK considers the value of the expression, and because it’s non-zero and non-empty, it executes the default action, which is to print `$0`.

The extra spaces are removed when AWK re-evaluates `$0`: it does so by concatenating all the fields using `OFS` as a separator, and that’s a single space by default. When AWK parses a record, `$0` contains the whole record, as-is, and `$1` to `$NF` contain the fields, without the separators; when any field is assigned to, `$0` is reconstructed from the field values.

Whether AWK outputs anything in this example is dependent on the input:

```
echo "0      0" | awk '$1=$1'
```

won’t output anything. `$1=$1` evaluates to whatever is in the first field, which is `0` in this case; that’s a “false” result in AWK, so nothing happens and nothing is output. To avoid that, turn `$1=$1` into an action and make AWK print the current record in all cases:

```
| awk '{$1=$1}1'
```

`1` causes AWK to always run the default action.