# How to remove duplicate lines ignoring tab or spaces

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I want to remove duplicate lines from `/etc/fstab`, so I did this:

```
 awk '!NF || !seen[$0]++'   /etc/fstab > /etc/fstab.update

UUID=3de0d101-fba7-4d89-b038-58fe07295d96 /grid/sdb ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
UUID=683ed0b3-51fe-4dc4-975e-d56c0bbaf0bc /grid/sdc ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
UUID=1cf79946-0ba6-4cd8-baca-80c0a2693de1 /grid/sdd ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
UUID=fa9cc6e8-4df8-4330-9144-ede46b94c49e /grid/sde ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
UUID=3de0d101-fba7-4d89-b038-58fe07295d96   /grid/sdb                      ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
UUID=683ed0b3-51fe-4dc4-975e-d56c0bbaf0bc   /grid/sdc                      ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

But as we can see, the last two lines are the same with the first two lines, but last two lines are with spaces.

Is it possible to ignore the space and remove the duplicate lines anyway?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Force the rebuild of the record with [`$1=$1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/568666)! This squeezes all contiguous spaces into a single one.

```
awk '{$1=$1};!seen[$0]++'
```

Comment: Ah, no new-lines should be remain, where your solutions removes them (if line is empty) as well. `"hello\n\nworld"` should remain as "hello\n\nworld" but your solutions removes the empty line as well. I was just asking could we prevent the empty new line to be removed.

Comment: @alper Well... That's an Awk script, the whole command-line to preserve blank lines is: `awk 'NF{$1=$1};!NF||!seen[$0]++' filename`.

Answer (score 6):

Use `tr` to replace tab with space and squeeze repeats (`-s`):

```
 tr -s $'\t' ' ' < /etc/fstab | awk '!NF || !seen[$0]++' > /etc/fstab.update
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this Perl one-liner to treat any amount of whitespace as a single blank:

```
perl -lane 'print unless $seen{"@F"}++' in.txt > out.txt
```

If you want to ignore whitespace completely, use:

```
perl -lane '$s = join "", @F; print unless $seen{$s}++' in.txt > out.txt
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)