# Remove duplicate lines with possibly different spacing, but ignore lines that start with #

Tags: text-processing, awk

This is a follow-up to an [earlier question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/637572/377345). I use this syntax in order to remove duplicate lines even if the fields are spaced differently

```
awk '{$1=$1};!NF||!seen[$0]++' /tmp/fstab
```

Now I want to exclude lines that start with `#`. So I use this syntax

```
awk '/^#/ || "'!'"'{$1=$1};!NF||!seen[$0]++' /tmp/fstab
-bash: !: event not found
```

What is wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
awk '!NF||$1~/^#/ {print; next} {$1=$1} !seen[$0]++' /tmp/fstab
```

This will immediately print unchanged any line which is empty or whose first field starts with `#` and then skip execution so that any further code is bypassed. All other lines will be rebuilt and printed as long as they have not yet been encountered.

The reason for checking if `$1~/^#/` instead of applying the match to the entire line (i.e. simply `/^#/`) is that this way we also catch comment lines where the `#` is preceded by whitespace. Although the manpage for `fstab` mandates that in order to qualify as comment line, the *first* character must be a `#`, as @StephenKitt noted, the Linux implementation of `libmount` will skip leading whitespace and accept a line as comment also if the *first non-whitespace* character is a `#`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `bash` is complaining (and not `awk`) and you have single quotes around your `!` the problem is obvious: you are exiting the command block of `awk`.

```
awk '{$1=$1} /^#/ || !seen[$0]++' file
```

I.e. do the operation, then the checks. Disadvantage: Will remove/reduce spaces in comments, too, however not remove such duplicates. Avoid that by first buffering the line:

```
awk  '{a=$0 ; $1=$1}  /^#/ || !seen[$0]++ {print a}' file
```

Input:

```
#comment
duplicate line
#comment
duplicate    line 
not duplicate
not duplicate 2
duplicate        line
#comment2
#comment2
#comment 3
#comment      3
```

Output  (first code)

```
#comment
duplicate line
#comment
not duplicate
not duplicate 2
#comment2
#comment2
#comment 3
#comment 3
```

Output  (second code)

```
#comment
duplicate line
#comment
not duplicate
not duplicate 2
#comment2
#comment2
#comment 3
#comment      3
```

Comment: not good because the duplicate line that have space will not removed

Comment: so need to use $1=$1};

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/637572/how-to-remove-duplicate-lines-ignoring-tab-or-spaces

Comment: @FelixJN `duplicate a` with one space, and `duplicate  a` with two spaces.

Comment: @yael I see, see correction.

Comment: @StephenKitt TY, was unaware of what was meant in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

`GNU sed` with extended regex mode turned ON `-E`

```
sed -Ee '
  # print empty|blank|comment lines
  /^\s*(#|$)/b
  s/\s+/ /g;s/^ | $//g;G;        # squeeze whitespace n append previous unique lines
  /^([^\n]*)\n(.*\n)?\1(\n|$)/d; # delete if seen
  P;h;d;                         # print seen first time then update seen list
'  file
```