# Save results from awk to a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, variable

I have a variable (that contains multiple lines of text) that I'm modifying using awk to replace the whitespace between fields with a comma and I'm trying to save it to another variable. This is what I'm doing at the moment:

```
VAR2=$(echo "$VAR1" | awk 'END {OFS=","}' 1)
```

However when I do `echo "$VAR2"`, it prints nothing but an empty line.

Comment: This sounds VERY much like you're using a shell (bash) to manipulate text, calling awk once in a while for specific operations, when you should instead be calling awk once total and using awk instead of shell to manipulate the text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your AWK script doesn’t output anything. But you don’t need AWK to replace spaces with commas; assuming you’re using a shell such as Bash, you can use

```
VAR2="${VAR1// /,}"
```

or with any shell,

```
VAR2=$(printf "%s" "$VAR1" | tr -s '[:blank:]' ,)
```

The former won’t collapse multiple spaces; if that’s important, enable `extglob` (`shopt -s extglob`) and use

```
VAR2="${VAR1//+( )/,}"
```

If you want to use AWK, you need to print *after* [forcing it to update records with the new output separator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/568666/86440):

```
VAR2=$(printf %s "$VAR1" | awk -v OFS=, '{$1=$1} 1')
```

Comment: @SMRV10 see the link I added for `{$1=$1}`. `1` is a shortcut for the default action, which is to print.

Answer (score 1):

```
var2=$(awk '{gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,",",$0);print }' filename)
```

output

```
echo $var2
praveen,ajay,san
```